# File does not exist:/var/www/skin, /var/www/js, /var/www/media

Tags: error, store-view, file-upload

I installed Debian in our local network and copy Magento to test.
After, I update the table `mage_core_config_data` in the database.

When I test this link dev-pmc/dev1.pmc.loc, I got this error in the log of apache

> [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/js, referer: http://dev-pmc/dev1.pmc.loc/
>   [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/skin, referer: xxxxx
>   [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/skin, referer: xxx
>   [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/skin, referer: xxxx
>   [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/skin, referer: xxx
>   [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/skin, referer: xxx
>   [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/skin, referer: xxxx
>   [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/skin, referer: xxxxx
>   [Thu Feb 26 10:43:56 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.141] File does not exist: /var/www/skin, referer: http://dev-pmc/dev1.pmc.loc/skin/frontend/seasons/home/css/styles.css

When I copy the folder skin, js and media in /www/, there are no error.

And I get this error too when I try to go to a store view
The requested URL dev1.pmc.loc/frw was not found on this server.
and in the server: File does not exist: /var/www/dev1.pmc.loc/frw

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we're all missing the obvious. Document root is/var/www and you're trying to run a Magento in a subdirectory. Base URLs should be adjusted and when using Apache, RewriteBase should be adjusted in .htaccess.

But since these are fake domains under your control, why not just use mod vhost alias or similar solutions? Less headaches.

Comment: HI @Melvyn, How can I use the two methods? I use your first method in this link http://husseycoding.blogspot.ca/2013/01/installing-magento-in-subdirectory.html, but it did not work. I put in the .htaccess file,                           Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev-pmc$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev1.pmctire.loc/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dev1.pmctire.loc/$1              It is not work

Comment: Start with the base URL. It should be http://dev-pmc/. The trailing slash is important. Then follow that advice from hussey to the letter.

Comment: sorry, I did't understand what you try to say. where to start with base Url?

Answer (score 0):

You need these:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh

Instructions. Follow them.

Comment: This link is for a new installation. But My problem is not the same. My magento works perfectly in production. and I copied the existing code in our local server which hostname is dev-pmc, and I created a site name dev1.pmc.loc. thanks

Comment: Is your production site using a CDN?  Check with `n98-magerun db:query 'SELECT path, value FROM mage_core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "web/%/%_url"'`. Oh yeah, [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/). Learn it, use it, love it.

Comment: web/unsecure/base_url http://b1.xxxx.re/
web/secure/base_url https://b1.xxxx.re/
web/unsecure/base_link_url {{unsecure_base_url}}
web/unsecure/base_skin_url {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
web/unsecure/base_media_url {{unsecure_base_url}}media/
web/unsecure/base_js_url {{unsecure_base_url}}js/
web/secure/base_link_url {{secure_base_url}}
web/secure/base_skin_url {{secure_base_url}}skin/
web/secure/base_media_url {{secure_base_url}}media/
web/secure/base_js_url {{secure_base_url}}js/
web/unsecure/base_url http://b1.xxxx.re/

Comment: web/secure/base_url https://b1.xxxx.re/
web/unsecure/base_url http://b1.xxxx.re/
web/secure/base_url https://b1.xxxx.re/
web/unsecure/base_url http://b1.xxxx.re/
web/secure/base_url https://b1.xxxx.re/
web/unsecure/base_url http://b1.xxxx.re/
web/secure/base_url https://b1.xxxx.re/